# Reuse arrayBuffer for fetch response

Tags: javascript, performance, fetch-api, arraybuffer

I use `fetch` API to perform HTTP requests. Because the HTTP response body is a binary, I use `response.arrayBuffer()` method to get the result as bytes.
Anyway, this approach doesn't perform well when the application makes a lot of HTTP requests because every time `response.arrayBuffer` method is invoked, it returns a new instance of `ArrayBuffer`. I didn't find any solution to provide my own `ArrayBuffer`  instance to the `Response` method to avoid a new allocation.

Is there any solution I can follow to let my application perform better?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for BYOB (bring your own buffer) when using [`response.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer). You could manually consume its [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) (on [`response.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body)) and work with your own buffer in that custom implementation. If this explanation is satisfactory as answer, I can provide it as one — but the implementation will be case-specific and is probably out of scope for an answer.

Comment: @jsejcksn, does this improve the performance? I mean, I need to copy chunks manually with streams, and this copy can reduce the performance.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77521999/reuse-arraybuffer-for-fetch-response#comment136667385_77521999) @allevo Only your performance tests can verify if your performance needs are met.

Comment: The problem isn't that you get a new array buffer each time, the problem is your need to copy the response into an array buffer. That copying expense is the same whether it's new or old.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly `response.arrayBuffer()` could be reused directly. A possible workaround would be to split the response into `chunks` and create multiple buffers from it using `Buffer.concat`:

```
const response = await fetch('url');
const chunks = [];
for await (const chunk of response.body) {
    chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
}
await sharp(Buffer.concat(chunks)).toFile('name');
await sharp(Buffer.concat(chunks)).toFile('name1');
```